# Ionic View on ionic2 doesn't update

Tags: config, ionic2, ionic-view

This is my first try developing with ionic v2.

I'm trying to use the **Ionic View** service to see a preview from my app on my mobile phone. 
It works very well the first time, but when i modify something in my code and run **ionic update** again, it looks like updating, but it doesn't update at all.

I had the same issue with ionic v1, but my best solution was always to delete the **ionic.project** file before running the **ionic update** command, and it has always worked good.
I can't find this file in my ionic2 project.

Anyone knows where it is? or maybe knows a better solution por this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a little bit late but you can find two files one is ionic.config and delete the app id and then there is .io-config and delete the app id there as well and that should fix that. Also clear the app cache in the view app before viewing it.